# Reduce rows in a group based on a column value using Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I want to implement Netting in the sense of reducing rows in each group based on below conditions:
- if the UNITS column has negative and positive values across rows in each group, do arithmetic sum. And the final row will have Amt from the row that has
the more amount.
- If Units has only positive or negative values in a group, then we pass the all the rows as-is

Out of this below dataset below, I want to do netting but am unable to figure out as this is not aggregation:

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|store|prod  |amt |units|
+-----+------+----+-----+
|West |Apple |2.0 |-10  |
|West |Apple |3.0 |10   |
|West |Orange|5.0 |-15  |
|West |Orange|17.0|-15  |
|South|Orange|3.0 |9    |
|South|Orange|6.0 |-18  |
|East |Milk  |5.0 |-5   |
|West |Milk  |5.0 |8    |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

Summing should happen if there is atleast 2 rows with opposite sign Units. That is in group below:

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|West |Apple |2.0 |-10  |
|West |Apple |3.0 |10   |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

There are 2 rows with -10 and 10, so this group will reduce to zero rows, as summing -10 and 10 is Zero.

But in below group, the difference between the Units is -9:

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|South|Orange|3.0 |9    |
|South|Orange|6.0 |-18  |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

... the result of this group would be taking 
- amt from the row that has more units.
- difference in units.

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|South|Orange|6.0 |-9  |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

Any rows in group that dont contain both negative and positive numbers would pass-thru straight.

So the final dataset should look as below:

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|store|prod  |amt |units|
+-----+------+----+-----+
|West |Orange|5.0 |-15  |
|West |Orange|17.0|-15  |
|South|Orange|6.0 |-9  |
|East |Milk  |5.0 |-5   |
|West |Milk  |5.0 |8    |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

Below rows are ...
a) removed

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|West |Apple |2.0 |-10  |
|West |Apple |3.0 |10   |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

or

b) reduced

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|South|Orange|3.0 |9    |
|South|Orange|6.0 |-18  |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

to

```
+-----+------+----+-----+
|South|Orange|6.0 |-9  |
+-----+------+----+-----+
```

Comment: The easiest might be to add a column whether there are two different signs per group (via window  functions) and then split the df into those that need to be reduced and those that don't. On those that need to be reduced you can then do `df.groupBy($"store", $"prod").agg(last($"amt").over(w).alias("amt"), sum($"units").alias("units"))` with `w = Window.groupBy($"store", $"prod").orderBy(abs($"units"))`. Finally you filter for the reduced df not being 0. In the end you need to union both dataframes

Comment: Paul, thanks. Below is what I did with Window functions, unable to give a value say "Yes" for a group that has both negative and positive Units.
    val window = Window.partitionBy("store", "prod").orderBy("units")
    val result = rawDf
      .withColumn("PosNeg",  row_number().over(window))
      .where($"units" > 0 || $"units" < 0)
    result.printSchema()
    result.show()
Will give result for above in the next comment ...

Comment: +-----+------+----+-----+------+
|store|  prod| amt|units|PosNeg|
+-----+------+----+-----+------+
|South|Orange| 3.0|    9|     1|
|South|Orange| 6.0|   18|     2|
| West|Orange| 5.0|  -15|     1|
| West|Orange|17.0|  -15|     2|
| East|  Milk| 5.0|   -5|     1|
| West| Apple| 2.0|  -10|     1|
| West| Apple| 3.0|   10|     2|
| West|  Milk| 5.0|    8|     1|
+-----+------+----+-----+------+

Do I need to group by $"store" and $"prod" again in this <result> dataframe?

If I use this below, I get no rows at all:
where($"units" > 0 || $"units" < 0)

Comment: I just noticed there was a little error in the above comment. So I decided to wrapt it up in an answer and tested it. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 1):

Just wrapping my comment up in an answer.
I've checked the following code in the spark-shell and it worked.

```
# create dataframe
val data = Seq(
("West" ,"Apple" ,2.0 ,-10  ),
("West" ,"Apple" ,3.0 ,10   ),
("West" ,"Orange",5.0 ,-15  ),
("West" ,"Orange",17.0,-15  ),
("South","Orange",3.0 ,9    ),
("South","Orange",6.0 ,-18  ),
("East" ,"Milk"  ,5.0 ,-5   ),
("West" ,"Milk"  ,5.0 ,8    ))
val df_raw = spark.createDataFrame(data)
val col_names = Seq("store", "prod", "amt", "units")
val df = df_raw.toDF(col_names: _*)

# define window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy($"prod", $"store")

# add should_reduce flag via window function
val should_reduce_df = df.withColumn("should_reduce", (max($"units").over(w) > 0) && (min($"units").over(w) < 0))

# select those that are only passed on / not reduced
val pass_df = should_reduce_df.filter(!$"should_reduce").select(col_names.head, col_names.tail: _*)

# reduce those that we need to reduce
# maximum amount and sum of units
# finally filter out those that reduce to 0 units
val reduced_df = should_reduce_df.filter($"should_reduce").groupBy($"store", $"prod").agg(max($"amt").alias("amt"), sum($"units").alias("units")).filter($"units" !== 0)

# do a union of passed-on and reduced df
val final_df = pass_df.union(reduced_df)
final_df.show()
```

Comment: thanks for the code. It really helped, it works for <amt> being a number. Now the column amt is a string variable like an ID. Obviously we cant agg(max()) on <amt> in this case. How do we change the below line in this case when <amt> is a actually a string "ID01", "ID02" etc --> val reduced_df = should_reduce_df.filter($"should_reduce").groupBy($"store", $"prod").agg(max($"amt").alias("amt"), sum($"units").alias("units")).filter($"units" !== 0)

Comment: My whole input has way more columns as shown below: +----------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
|ACCOUNT_NO|CostCenter|BU    |MPU   |STORE|LONG_IND|SHORT_IND|PROD|QUANTITY|
+----------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
|37903484  |null      |BOXXBU|BOXXMP|APPLE         |1525    |6525     |163J8      |-2000   |
|90915301  |null      |BOXXBU|BOXXMP|APPLE         |1524    |6524     |163J8      |3763    |... but I have to group by only <store> and <prod> ... but have to still get the other columns

Comment: in case your amt column is ID+zero-padded numbers the alphabetical order on strings acutally corresponds to the numeric order on integers and hence you can actually use max() as aggregation. For the other columns you can simply use `first` as aggregation (assuming per group there is only one distinct value - otherwise the aggregation is non-unique anyway)

Comment: Thanks Paul but I couldn't get this to execute. Really appreciate your help.